# Eclipse Error: "Unable to locate executable for jre7"

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

Eclipse keeps giving me the above error when trying to run my test class. JDK is properly installed and I've never gotten an error like this with other IDEs.

Comment: Downvoted for lack of research effort and further information.

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure it's correctly configured under :

```
Window > preferences > Java > Installed JREs
```

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary that you indicate the location of the jre. You must go to Window / Preferences, and then

1. Java / Installed JREs: to indicate the location of JREs (you delete the old one and you add the new folder (jdk or jre)

OR

2. Java / Installed JREs / Execution Environments: To associate and JRE runtime environment (JavaSE #your-version) - have to get out and return the preference to confirm the new location.

Answer (score 0):

Set it in your build path, right click project > properties > build path