# Unable to locate executable for jre1.8.0_77

Tags: java, eclipse

Says on my eclipse "Unable to locate executable for jre1.8.0_77". It also deleted the JREs :( I tried to run my project and went into Windows and preferences to add it but I couldn't.

Comment: did you change it on the project level as well.

Comment: This question is almost certainly a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29693969/eclipse-error-unable-to-locate-executable-for-jre7)

Answer (score 19):

- Go to Windows > Preferences.
- Locate Java > Installed JREs. (Or simply type JREs in the search
  box).
- The screen will show the list of JREs.
- Click on Add button, locate the new folder on your machine and select.
- Remove the old JRE from the list.

Same Question has asked before and here's the Link - [How to change default JRE for all Eclipse workspaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15099530/how-to-change-default-jre-for-all-eclipse-workspaces)

Answer (score 8):

Maybe you updated Java version but your PC's environment variable for JRE is still referring to the old version of JRE. If you updated Java, update your environment variable also.

Comment: That's exactly what happened to me. I updated Java version and then I had to update my installed JRE under: Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

recently i encountered same issue,
this happened after i updated my **jre**
because of this there was mismatch with **jdk** and **jre** versions

uninstalled java and installed newer **JDK** (**SE** ) kit. https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
now both jdk and jre are same

Comment: If you updated jre while eclipse was running, restart eclipse.